# How long do deleted questions live in the system?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

How much time do deleted posts live on for before they get cleared from the database? I'm asking because I can't find a question of my own. It got deleted few months back, but it has some insights I'd like to recover.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Answer (score 2):

They don't actually get deleted (at least in non-exceptional cases), but once deleted you need 10K rep to be able to see them.  If you know the question number, you should be able to see your own deleted question, however.  Using the question number you can build the URL that will take you there.

I did a basic search via google using your user name and "deleted by" and didn't come up with anything.  Perhaps if you could give me (us) some keywords that would fit, I could find it for you and give you the question number/link to the question.

Comment: A Google search wont find deleted posts - Google doesn't have >10k rep :P

Comment: You can see your own deleted answers, but not questions.

Comment: Google cache or the Way Back Machine (http://www.archive.org/web/web.php) might have it if it were crawled before being deleted. @PopularDemand - you used to be able to see deleted answers IF you retained a link.  There's no way to find them internally that I know of, but if you had bookmarked it or found it in a web cache somewhere it used to be that you could still view them.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might have been one of those "it was true back in the day" situations. That hasn't worked in over a year, though.

Answer (score -1):

The very first question (id 1, a test question) was deleted from Stack Overflow about a year ago, and it's still there..

If you recall the title, someone should be able to find it for you