# How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?

Tags: support, faq, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-posts

What circumstances can cause a question or answer to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?

- How can a post be deleted?
- When can't I delete my own post?
- Can I still see my post even after it's deleted?
- Can I see a list of my deleted posts?
- How can I undelete one of my posts?
- What does deletion *mean* for a post?
- How do votes to delete work?
- What are the criteria for deletion?
- What else should I know about deleted posts?
- If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?

> For more information, see the articles about [deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) and [deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: See also [When should I vote to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete)

Comment: Related: (Software Recommendations SE) [Userscript or extension to indicate when a Stack Exchange question is scheduled for auto-deletion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17905/623)

Answer (score 404, accepted):

### How can a post be deleted?

#### By users:

1. **The author** can typically delete their own posts at will; for exceptions, see *When* can't *I delete my own post?* below. To delete a post, just use the *delete* link below it, on the left.
2. **Diamond moderators (♦)** can delete any post instantly. This group includes elected and appointed volunteer moderators as well as Stack Exchange employees with moderator privileges (such as [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341)).
3. **Users with reputation ≥ 2k** (more precisely, the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit); 1k on sites with "beta" requirements) [can cause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/152859) automatic deletion of a post if they choose *recommend deletion* from within the low-quality review queue (see number 14 below).
4. **Users with reputation ≥ 10k** (more precisely, the [*access to moderator tools* privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k on sites with "beta" requirements) can vote to delete *questions* that have been [closed or marked as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work) at least 48 hours ago. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), but ten votes at most.
5. **Users with reputation ≥ 20k** (more precisely, the [*trusted user* privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user); 4k on sites with "beta" requirements), can vote to delete closed questions *within* 48 hours of being closed, *so long as* they score −3 or lower. They may also vote to delete *answers* of score −1 or lower (0 or lower if through the Low Quality Posts review queue), [including accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286049) (unless they are the owner of that answer). It takes three votes to delete an answer.

#### By flags:

6. [The system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) (i.e., the Community user) will automatically delete any post [red flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) enough times as *rude or abusive* or *spam*. It takes four red flags from normal users, or a single one from a moderator, to delete a post for this reason.

#### By the [automated cleanup scripts](/help/roomba) (i.e. “Roomba”):

7. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) closed, unlocked, and non-migrated questions that have zero or negative score, have no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, were closed for any reason other than duplicate nine or more days ago, and haven't been edited in the past nine days. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedClosed" in the question timeline)
8. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) [rejected migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/377214) that were rejected more than 30 days ago. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveRejectedMigrations" in the question timeline)
9. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) negatively-scored, non-migrated, unlocked, and unanswered questions (both open and closed, including as duplicates) that are older than 30 days. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions" in the question timeline)
10. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) unlocked, unanswered questions older than 365 days on main (non-meta) sites, that have a score of zero (or have a score of 1 and the owner's account is deleted), have fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedQuestions" in the question timeline)
11. The system will automatically delete migration stubs (original site copies of questions migrated to other sites, which haven't been rejected by the destination site) [that are at least 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082). Questions deleted under this criterion still have their revision histories visible to everyone, and links to them redirect to the new question instead of showing an error page. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveMigrationStubs" in the question timeline)

#### By account removal:

12. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote) any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, *unless* the post is [an open question that has at least one positively-scored answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote/312594#312594), or [is on a meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278218/377214). (shown as "User [x] deleted" in the question timeline)
13. The system will automatically delete any post, regardless of score, answers, or the site it's on, when its owner's account is [destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user) (only done for spammers and blatant trolls). (shown as "User [x] destroyed" in the question timeline)

#### By review:

14. Answers with zero or negative score that receive six *recommend deletion* reviews (four on Stack Overflow) in the Low Quality Posts (LQP) review queue are automatically deleted "from review". Answers can be kicked into this queue either automatically or with *very low quality* and *not an answer* flags, and can be removed from the queue if enough *Looks OK* reviews are cast toward them. (Posts with a positive score will not be deleted through this route if the outcome is for deletion, but a flag will be raised to let moderators know of the outcome.)

    Note that trusted users, provided they still have delete votes, can exercise their delete votes in that queue, provided the answer has a score of 0 or lower. If three delete votes are cast (visible in the review as **Delete** rather than **Recommend Deletion**) then the **≥ 20k** rules in number 5 above apply. Otherwise, a "Delete" review will count the same as a "Recommend Deletion" review.

#### By side effects:

15. When a question is deleted, all its answers are also automatically deleted.

### When *can't* I delete my own post?

You can't delete your own *answer* if it has been [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about).

You can't delete your own *question* if it:

- has an [answer which received at least one up vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
- has an accepted answer
- has multiple answers (even if there are no up votes)
- [has an answer with an awarded bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele)
- has at least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question

As an example, a question with this answer cannot be self-deleted:
[image: answer with the acceptance tick and upvote arrows lit up, and a net score of -3]

You can't delete any of your own posts if [you've already deleted five of your own posts on the same day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85523/377214) (with exceptions).

*Unregistered* users (users who haven't registered their account - that is, associated a Google, Facebook, or Stack Exchange account with it) can't delete any of their own posts.

Note: if you're a moderator, most of the above don't apply; you can delete your own post even if it wouldn't ordinarily be allowed (the only exception is if another question is closed as a duplicate of your question).

### Can I still see my own post even after it's deleted?

Yes, you can see any of your own deleted questions, and your own deleted answers to any question.

When you open one of your own deleted questions, it will show with a red background, and the cause of the deletion will be indicated at the top. When browsing a question where you've posted a deleted answer, your answer will also show with the same red background and notice at the top. If you've sorted the answers by date modified or date created, or if you've sorted by highest score and lack the moderator tools privilege, your deleted answer will be shown in the same spot where it would otherwise show if it weren't deleted; if you have the moderator tools privilege and sort by highest score, it will show at the bottom along with other deleted answers (if any).

Additionally, if you answered a question that was subsequently deleted, you can see the deleted question and your answer(s) to it, but you can't see other users' answers to it, neither can you see the question's revision history or timeline, unless you have the moderator tools privilege. This applies even if your answer was deleted before the question was deleted.

### Can I see a list of my deleted posts, or find links to them?

You can find lists of your deleted questions and answers from your profile. If you go to the Questions subtab of your profile, at the bottom you can click on ["Deleted questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current). This will give you a list of your deleted questions. You can find deleted answers in the same way - by clicking on ["Deleted answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current) in the Answers subtab.

If you have the moderator tools privilege, you can [search among your own deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users) using `deleted:1`.

### When can I see others' deleted posts?

If you have the *access to moderator tools* privilege (10k+ rep on designed sites, 2k+ rep on beta and non-designed sites), you can see any deleted question that you have the direct link to, and see all deleted answers to all questions (deleted or not). Note that if the post was deleted as spam or abusive, you cannot see its body directly: you have to navigate to its revision history to see it.

If you answered a deleted question, you can always see the deleted question along with your own deleted answer.

Additionally, all users can see revision histories of questions and answers migrated to other sites. This is to comply with CC BY-SA license requirements, to supply attribution to users who edited a post before it was migrated. You can access these pages via the destination site either by clicking the "Migrated [x time ago]" link in the question's notice (only for questions migrated within the last 60 days), or by going to the post's revision history or timeline and clicking the "revisions" link on the migration event. (Due to a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372072/links-to-migrated-answers-revision-histories-incorrectly-go-to-the-parent-quest), to access the revision history of a migrated answer, one must use a URL modification detailed in that post.)

### What are the criteria for deletion?

For questions, if it [no longer adds *anything* to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/148099), it should be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened. However, it may be beneficial to keep duplicates to aid future users in finding the canonical question, as different people may use different wordings that cause the canonical question to not show up in search.

For answers, any post that is [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099) (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice [should be downvoted, not deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264294/1).

These are general guidelines; some communities in the network may impose additional requirements for posts or have specific reasons for deleting posts that don't apply to other network sites. For example, on Puzzling.SE, [answers to a puzzle without explanation are subject to deletion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation), and some technical sites will delete answers which are not only wrong but also harmful when tried.

### How can I undelete one of my posts?

Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. While self-deleted *answers* can be edited by the author without undeleting, self-deleted *questions* cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first [for spam prevention reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296101/349538).

Depending on who deleted your post, you may or may not be able to undelete it. If it was deleted by...

- you, the author: you can undelete it
- multiple high-reputation users<sup>1</sup> or the Community user: you can vote to undelete, but it will require more votes from high-reputation users or a moderator to undelete
- a moderator: you cannot undelete it, and high-reputation users cannot vote to undelete; the only ones who can undelete them are moderators
- from review (without three trusted users voting to delete): you [can undelete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/259867), but doing so will alert moderators

You cannot undelete your own post if it is [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post).

If your post was deleted by [high-reputation users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) or [by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/how-can-a-question-deleted-by-community-be-undeleted), it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted (more if it's a question and it was popular) - politely asking for this on the per-site meta may attract the necessary votes if you make a good case for why the question should be restored (i.e. why the post doesn't meet the deletion criteria above). Do note that if the question was deleted by the Community user, it must be fixed so that the automatic deletion criteria no longer apply; otherwise, it will be re-deleted once the script runs again.

If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag that post, writing a note in the "in need of moderator intervention" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion. Be sure to clearly indicate in your flag why the post does not meet the criteria for deletion outlined above. If your request is declined, or as an alternative, you can make a request on the per-site meta per the above paragraph.

### What does deletion mean for a post?

Deleted posts are usually **not** physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted). This means they won't appear in search results or data dumps, and normal users following links to them will see [a 404 (not found) page explaining the cause of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2). Links to deleted answers will redirect to the question they were on. Links to deleted questions will either show as "voluntarily removed by its author" if the author deleted it, or as "removed from [site] for reasons of moderation" if it was deleted for any other reason.

Moderators, and normal users with the moderator tools privilege (10k on "full" requirement sites, 2k on "beta" requirement sites), can see all deleted posts that they have links to. Users without the privilege can see their own deleted posts (see *Can I still see my own post even after it's deleted?* above). Moderators are able to undelete any deleted post.

Users with the moderator tools privilege may vote to undelete deleted *questions*: it usually takes three votes to undelete a question, but [sometimes more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/259867).

Users with the trusted user privilege (20k on "full" requirement sites, 4k on "beta" requirement sites) may also vote to undelete deleted *answers*: it takes three votes to undelete an answer.

Regardless of the above, normal users cannot vote to undelete posts that were deleted by moderators<sup>1</sup>

### Does deleting my own posts or having them deleted by others affect my standing on a site?

First, having a post deleted automatically by receiving four *spam* or *rude or abusive* flags, or a single one from a moderator, will levy a 100-reputation penalty on your profile. Repeatedly making posts that get flagged for this reason may result in you being suspended from the site.

Second, deleting multiple posts can lead to [question or answer bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), particularly if you have other posts which are downvoted or closed and you have few well-received posts. Single posts are not a problem, but a series of deletions can lead to a post ban. As a general rule, it is better to try to fix a post than to delete it.

Finally, deleting useful content, whether your own or posted by others, may also lead to moderator intervention. In particular, deleting any amount of useful content (even a single post) may be considered [vandalism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304868/removing-answers-in-mass-damaging-the-site-is-that-really-acceptable?noredirect=1&lq=1), even if the automated system does not prevent you from deleting that content. In general, users are trusted to evaluate the usefulness of their own posts, but don't have a guaranteed right to remove their content, as detailed in the below section *If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?*. Continually abusing the system to delete your useful posts or misusing system features to delete others' useful posts may result in a suspension.

(Moderators will be automatically notified if a user deletes large parts of their own content, both when it's done in a short period of time and when done over longer periods of time.)

### How do votes to delete work?

- If you have the [vote to delete privilege (part of the "moderator tools" privilege)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k rep on launched sites, 2k on beta sites), you get five votes to delete per day, [plus 1 vote per 1000 reputation points above 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de/105876#105876) ([up to a maximum of 30 votes per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)). Votes to delete your own posts [may or may not count toward the limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274757), depending on circumstances.
- The total number of votes you have to undelete per day will be the same as the total number of votes you have to delete per day.
- You cannot vote to undelete posts that were deleted by a moderator (♦)<sup>1</sup>.
- Votes to delete or undelete never expire.
- You can only vote to delete once per post, except your own posts, which you can vote to delete as many times as you want.
- You can only vote to undelete once per post, except your own posts, which you can vote to undelete as many times as you want.
- If there are pending delete votes on a post that no longer has the required negative score to vote to delete (answers with a score of 0 or higher, or questions closed within the last 48 hours with a score of -2 or higher), the button to delete will disappear, but prior delete votes will still remain pending, unless cleared by a change in state of the post (see below point). Such pending votes are only shown in the 10k tools' Delete statistics, as well as on the post itself to the author and moderators.
- If a closed question is reopened, any pending delete votes on it [will be cleared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353607/how-do-i-vote-against-pending-delete-votes/353613#353613).
- If a question's popularity drops to a point where the current number of pending delete/undelete votes would be enough to cause the respective action (e.g., a question has five pending delete votes and used to require six, then its score dropped so now it only requires five), it will not be deleted/undeleted immediately - one more vote will be required to result in action. In other words, the check to see if the post should be deleted/undeleted is only run when such a vote is cast on the post.

### If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?

The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags. The reasoning is as follows:

- If you can delete your post yourself (because it has no answers, the only answer has no upvotes, or it's not an accepted answer), then you should do it. It doesn't require moderator intervention.
- If you cannot delete your post because you've already deleted five of your own posts today, keep in mind that this limit exists [in order to prevent users from "rage quitting"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172029/377214). If you believe your post should be deleted, you should wait until the next day to delete it, rather than flag.
- If you cannot delete your question because it has an upvoted answer, multiple answers, or an answer with an awarded bounty: deleting the question also deletes the answers. Deleting the answers undoes the hard work other people have put in to answer your question, and reverses the reputation they have earned too. This is not fair to the answerers of your question.
- If you cannot delete your question because there are other questions closed as duplicates of your question: if you were allowed to delete the question, then it would be extremely confusing for other users, as they'd be directed to a deleted question when attempting to browse the site for answers and stumble upon the duplicate question(s). Moderators are also prevented from deleting such questions for this reason.
- If you cannot delete your answer, then it must have been accepted by the question author. One of the main points of these sites is to provide help to others searching for answers; deleting your answer that the author has indicated as helpful to them detracts from maintaining such a knowledge base.

If you made a post that you regret posting because:

- it is a school assignment and you have now violated your school's "honor code"
- it is embarrassing because it is a silly question

…then deleting the post is not a solution, because users with 10k (2k on beta sites) reputation can still see it anyway. It is also [clear in Public Network Terms of Service (section 6)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) that:

> You agree that any and all content, ... that you provide to the public Network (collectively, "Subscriber Content"), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you as reasonably necessary...

Moderators will not delete your post for the above reasons.

Instead, you can [have the post dissociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732).

#### What if I posted my employer's copyrighted code, or there is a copyright violation in my question, and for legal reasons it has to be removed?

Stack Exchange implements a take-down process in accordance with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA). If you are a copyright holder, and someone has posted content which contravenes your copyright, then you can [file a copyright take-down and the content will be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#copyright).

Flagging the post for moderator attention is not the right process to follow, as Stack Exchange staff are the only ones who can perform a DMCA removal, and only after the formal process *by the copyright holder* has been followed. Moderator flags requesting removal solely on copyright grounds (especially when you are *not* the copyright holder) will be declined.

#### What if I accidentally posted log-in credentials or other such sensitive information?

In that case, replace the relevant information with dummy text/data/code that fulfills the same purpose, as outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278716), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327145) — both from your question and any answer that might have used it — **and take care not to break context of the post, especially if answers are already present**. After all that's done, flag the post for moderator attention and ask that they redact the sensitive information from the post's revision history.

### What else should I know about deleted posts?

- Reputation changes from votes (both up and down), bounties (both giving on questions and receiving on answers), acceptances, and approved suggested edits on deleted posts (including answers to deleted questions) are nullified. Two exceptions:

  - First, reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, [is retained](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). This does *not* include reputation lost from giving bounties on them (this will be nullified as normal). This rule does not apply to posts deleted [via the plagiarism flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749).
  - Second, if a question that has had bounties awarded to answers is deleted, and one or more of the answers would get to retain their reputation per the above first exception, the bounty reputation given to those answers will not be refunded to the bounty owner(s).
- Reputation lost as a penalty for having a post deleted by spam or "rude or abusive" flagging is not returned, unless a moderator manually clears the spam or abuse flags. This only happens if the post was deleted in error (a moderator pressed the wrong button, or multiple users [conspired to have it deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223297/what-if-six-users-conspire-to-nuke-posts-with-spam-flags)).
- The first time you delete your own post that has a score of 3 or higher, you will earn a [Disciplined badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges/35/disciplined).
- The first time you delete your own post that has a score of -3 or lower, you will earn a [Peer Pressure badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges/36/peer-pressure).
- Answers are automatically deleted when the question they're attached to is deleted. Such answers are automatically undeleted when the question is undeleted, except for answers that were deleted *before* the question was deleted.

---

<sup>1</sup> The check to see if a diamond user has deleted a post only checks their **current** diamond status. This means that if a post that was deleted by normal user votes, but any of said users who voted to delete gain a diamond later (i.e., are elected or appointed as a moderator or get hired as a staff member in a role that entitles them to moderator rights), that post now cannot be undeleted except by another diamond user, even though the original delete vote was a non-binding vote. This also means that a post that was deleted with a binding vote from a user who no longer holds moderator rights can be undeleted by normal users.

Comment: "You can’t delete your own question when it: has an upvoted answer, or
has an accepted answer [...]". Which takes precedence here? Having 10k deletion tools (after 48hours of closure), or the fact that the question is your own?"

Comment: *Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified* - this makes it [seem like it's ok to self-delete badly received questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302687/reposting-a-closed-or-held-question/302689?noredirect=1#comment984454_302689), when in reality deleted downvoted posts still count towards an automatic question ban. I think that should be clarified.

Comment: Not able to delete my answer is against the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) rules! I'm not a lawyer, but this means that this interface is illegal to be use as much as I understand. Let's say for example that I posted in code in my answer a real password by mistake and now I want to delete it... THIS IS REALLY BAD! SINCE EDITING WILL NOT HELP AND I CANNOT DELETE AS WELL...

Comment: @RonenAriely https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/data-subjects

Comment: @FabianRöling you can always flag your own accepted answers and ask a moderator (nicely) to delete the answer (do explain why you feel it needs to be deleted).

Comment: I self-deleted a question of mine. It was not locked right before I deleted it. However for some reason it became locked when I deleted it, so apparently I can't undelete it! I deleted it because I thought it was no longer valid, but then I discovered that it was still valid. EDIT: just discovered that a background process called community locked it automatically, ugh)

Comment: @user3015682 Your question was probably migrated from another site, so when you deleted the question on the destination site, it marked it as a rejected migration which locked the question there (and unlocked the copy on the origin site).

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Possibly. I should have linked to the question here, it's been a few months and I don't remember which question I was referring to!

Comment: I'm scrolling through some old questions of mine and saw one that was closed and it currently stands at -1. Since it is closed (which I didn't agree at the time but whatever) and it has a negative score, why can't I delete it if it does not fit Stack Exchange standards? The question has an answer that indeed helped me, and I accepted it, but my point still stands.

Comment: I just found out that one of my questions was deleted. It's incredibly frustrating and saddening. I tried really hard to be specific, give examples, and ensure I'd get a high quality answer. It's a niche problem, so I was expecting it to take a long time before I got an answer. But someone randomly downvoted it a couple of days after I posted - no reason given. I tried asking but got no feedback. Now I found out the question was secretly deleted (bad UX; I got no notification or warning). This auto-delete system really sucks.

Comment: I clicked the delete button on an old question that I myself answered and got this: 'Delete this answered question?
We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to deletion.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?' That seemed riskey so I've left the question up despite a couple recent downvotes.

Comment: I recently posted an answer, immediately realised the answer was rubbish and deleted it. But, as I understand it, the damage was already done: the question was bumped to the homepage, giving it attention it did not need (I did not think to check whether this actually happened). If my understanding is correct, continuing this behaviour could be used to manipulate the homepage, and there should be a penalty for it. Is there? And speaking of penalties, how does the question ban work?

Comment: I'm a moderator on SE EE. If any of the above happen to users I'd be happy to attempt to remedy the problems to the extent that the system allows. | If an answer of mine has such a major issue that I'd wish to delete it (seldom, but it happens) I'd usually add a warning comment at the top and a brief summary of why. I may add a new answer if it seemed worthwhile - but incorrectness often become obvious when better and correct answers are posted.  Usually an incorrect answer has enough valuable material in it that it's worth leaving, as long as a suitable warning is added at the top.

Comment: "has an accepted answer" But I can reverse the aceptation of an answer.

Comment: I'm trying to improve my old questions, but this bot keeps deleting them, how can I get it to stop?

Comment: @AaarghZombies, search this page for the text: "The system will automatically delete" and read how to prevent that, also search this site (search bar above) for "Roomba".

Comment: @Rob, the mods need to get these questions more up votes, but I can't get them to stay on the site long enough for people to be able to read them,  let alone up vote them. is there any way to get them flagged so that the bot will keep them active for a little longer?

Comment: @AaarghZombies, on SO?, probably not; you have seconds to catch people's interest or else you scroll off the page, pick up a downvote and you are toast eventually. Later, people who follow tags might see your question and save or sink it. --- Lesson: Make the title and first paragraph interesting to the greatest audience and make the entire question at least fairly good; answers actually get more scrutiny, but questions can't be poorly researched or written either.

Comment: @AaarghZombies, you can bounty questions; if they live long enough to be eligible.

Comment: Is there a current discussion forum devoted to this issue?  Seems every time I log on there's more and more and more dead wood on SO -- either in the form of dead questions or in the form of questions without accepted answers.  I wonder if some of these questions are upvoted only because the review process suggests it.